# How to do a wild card search for part of a word?

Tags: mysql

How can I search for part of a word and return all records that partially match?

Example:

```
SELECT * WHERE vehiclename = "inf"
```

Showing tables

```
Vehicle ID: 3 Vehicle Name: Infernus
Vehicle ID: 5 Vehicle Name: Infinz
```

Comment: Did you want something  like the start of the string starts with instead otherwise  LIKE 'Inf%' .

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` with `%` within the search query for this.

```
SELECT * WHERE vehiclename LIKE "%inf%"
```

More information about this can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html